# Is there a way to delete elements of an array using elasticsearch update_by_query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

elasticsearch version : 7.8.1

```json
[
    ...
    {
        "target" : [
            { "docId" : "operator" },
            { "docId" : "test" },
            { "docId" : "abcde" },
        ]
    }
    ...
]
```

Hello?
I want to delete the element whose docId is operator from the above array called target in elasticsearch.

I tried the below but failed.
What part of my code is wrong?

```json
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "target": [
        {
          "docId": "operator"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": " for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.target.length(); i++) { if (ctx._source.target[i].docId == params.docId) { ctx._source.target.remove(i);}}",
    "params": {
      "docId": "operator"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any error? Can you check if the match clause works individiaully as a query?

Answer (score 0):

The query was wrong and length() was not a function either.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "target.docId": "operator"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": " for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.target.length; i++) { if (ctx._source.target[i].docId == params.docId) { ctx._source.target.remove(i);}}",
    "params": {
      "docId": "operator"
    }
  }
}
```